# Jenkins is adding Linux style slash to the JAVA path

Tags: java, linux, jenkins, configuration, administration

Hello I have a the following Jenkins configuration:

Master - MAC OS,

Slave - Windows 10

When the build is triggered I'm  receiving the below error message:

[Maven_Google_Project] $ **"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101/bin/java"** -cp C:\Jenkins\maven33-agent.jar;C:\maven-3.3.9\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar;C:\maven-3.3.9/conf/logging

As can be seen the to the Java path on the slave/Win10/ is added /bin/java Linux style slashes which I suppose cause the error. 
I checked all path configurations on Master and Slave and they all are correct:

Master: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_31.jdk/Contents/Home

Slave: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101

Thanks in Advance for your help.

Comment: Windows supports forward slashes in path names.

Comment: There's no error message there.